# How to sort a user Created List<UserClass> Collection in C#

Tags: c#

I wish to sort the collection `List<UserClass>`

on the basis of one of the property among various of that UserClass which is User Defined.

Is it valid

```
List<Function> objFunctionsList = new List<Function>(); 

// populating data in objFunctionsList 

objFunctionsList = objFunctionsList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: can i sort it using LINQ , although I can sort it perhaps using Comparer .

Comment: will this code create casting issue, i notice that we are actually created a copy after sorting , can't we sort the actual list ? so to achieve that thing i think i shud go for  this objFunctionsList.Sort((a, b) => a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name));

Comment: This code will not create a casting issue because it uses generics to remain type safe. The sort function will throw an exception if a.Name  is null (linq won't). You need to decide how much of a problem copying the list is.  Also how are you populating the list, you may be able to use linq during your populate routine to effectively skip the copy in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is list, then:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => {
                       if (a==null) return (b==null) ? 0 : -1;
                       if (b==null) return 1;
                       if (a.Property==null) return (b.Property==null) ? 0 : -1;
                       return a.Property.CompareTo(b.Property);
                     });
```

Comment: another great and concise syntax

Answer (score 6):

Just use the linq extension method orderby

```
var sorted=list.OrderBy(x=>x.MyProperty);
```

If you need a list as a result then add  `ToList()` eg

```
var sortedList=list.OrderBy(x=>x.MyProperty).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could use this Extension class

```
public static class SortExtension {

  public static Comparison<T> GetComparer<T, TP>(Expression<Func<T, IComparable<TP>>> propertyExpression) {

    if (propertyExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    var member = ((propertyExpression.Body is UnaryExpression) ? ((UnaryExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Operand : propertyExpression.Body) as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null) throw new ArgumentException();
    var parameterA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
    var parameterB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "b");
    var nullExpr = Expression.Constant(null);
    var valueA = Expression.Property(parameterA, member.Member.Name);
    var valueB = Expression.Property(parameterB, member.Member.Name);
    var compare = Expression.Call(valueA, typeof(TP).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(TP) }), valueB);
    var checkBPropNull = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(valueB, nullExpr), Expression.Constant(0), Expression.Constant(-1));
    var checkAPropertyNull = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(valueA, nullExpr), checkBPropNull, compare);
    var checkBNullANot = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(parameterB, nullExpr), Expression.Constant(1), checkAPropertyNull);
    var checkBNullANull = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(parameterB, nullExpr), Expression.Constant(0), Expression.Constant(-1));
    var checkANull = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(parameterA, nullExpr), checkBNullANull, checkBNullANot);
    return (a, b) => Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, int>>(checkANull, parameterA, parameterB).Compile()(a, b);
  }

  public static void SortBy<T, TP>(this List<T> source, Expression<Func<T, IComparable<TP>>> propertyExpression) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    source.Sort(GetComparer(propertyExpression));
  }
}
```

Then you can just do

list.SortBy(x=>x.MyProperty);

The Expression building produces a comparitor that is functionally equivalent to

```
list.Sort((a,b) => {
  if (a == null) return (b==null) ? 0 :-1;
  if (b==null) return 1;
  if (a.MyProperty == null) return (b.MyProperty==null) ? 0 : -1;
  return a.T1.CompareTo(b.T1);
});
```

Comment: Correct, but why create new List when he want to sort the existing list?

Comment: Yes that is valid, is it not working?  Did you reference System.Linq

Answer (score 2):

```
users.Sort((u1, u2) => {
    return u1.Age.CompareTo(u2.Age);
});
```

This will sort by `Age` for example.