# Sorting an object list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am keeping a list of objects in a `List()`. I want to sort this list by a property of the object.

For example, say the object is a Messsage and message has: content, date, header, ...

I want to sort the list by the message's date.

Is there any `List` method or any other method that makes this sort easy?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840808/how-to-sort-a-user-created-listuserclass-collection-in-c/6840825#6840825)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, use sort. If your list is l:

```
l.Sort((a,b) => {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a == null) return -1;
    if (b == null) return 1;

    return a.Date.CompareTo(b.Date)
});
```

This assumes that the date property is of type that implements CompareTo().

Comment: no need to check for b - the compareTo should handle it if implemented correctly

Comment: Nope, because you are passing in b.Date so if b==null then you will get a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IComparer<YourObject>` and use that comparer for sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using generics (ie using List) you can use the Sort method [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx)

See my answer ot [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840808/how-to-sort-a-user-created-listuserclass-collection-in-c/6840825#6840825) for out to create an extension method that lets you do

```
myList.SortBy(x=>x.Date)
```